# Represent complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to represent these complex numbers:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
z^3=i\overline{z}|z| \\ 
||z-i|-i|<\sqrt 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

The solutions of the first equation are:

$z_0=0$

$z_1=e^{i\frac{\pi}{8}}$

$z_2=e^{i\frac{5\pi}{8}}$

$z_3=e^{i\frac{9\pi}{8}}$

$z_4=e^{i\frac{13\pi}{8}}$

$z_5=e^{i\frac{17\pi}{8}}$

I seem to get stuck when I have to find the solutions of the second equation.

I think that the result might be a circle without boundary.

Answer (score 0):

For second part, let $|z-i|=p$, where $p \in \Bbb R^+$.

We are given that $$|p-i|<\sqrt 2 \implies \sqrt{p^2+1} <\sqrt 2 \implies p <1$$

So you need to solve for $$|z-i|<1$$

Which is simply the interior of a circle of unit radius and centre at $(0,i)$.

Comment: @gefavasej if you have any questions left then please let me know.